# How do you break a running program under gud?

Tags: gud

In the vanilla `gdb` interface, I can hit `C-c` to break the running program, insert breakpoints, etc., and then run `continue` to resume execution of the program being debugged.  Is this possible with `gud`?  `C-c C-c` in `gud` actually sends `SIGKILL` to the program, rather than breaking in `gdb`...

---

#### More info and repro

I'm actually trying to debug `emacs` (from a separate `emacs+gud` instance, of course) to try to get to the bottom of [this guy](https://debbugs.gnu.org/db/19/19320.html).  Here's what I'm doing:

```
$ cd path/to/emacs-24.5 # where I've built emacs with debugging symbols, etc
$ ./src/emacs -Q
M-x gdb
Run gdb (like this): gdb -i=mi ./src/emacs
run
```

At this point I'd like to break the execution of the new `emacs` process so that I can poke around, set breakpoints, etc.  My end game is to wait for the new `emacs` process to get into the bad state described in [my bug report](https://debbugs.gnu.org/db/19/19320.html) (sometimes takes days).  That's when I really want to break execution of emacs and set the breakpoints.

Comment: Maybe you could send `SIGINT` to the gdb process?

Comment: That actually kills my process as well...  I'm guessing that's because `gdb` is running in `gdb -i=mi` mode so `SIGINT` is probably handled differently.

Comment: Ping!  Do either of the posted answers help you?

Comment: Neither of the solutions worked... I'll try some more things and try to get some closure on this.

Comment: IIRC the issue is specific to debugging `emacs`, where you'll want to use `C-c C-z`, instead of `C-c C-c`.  My memory is fuzzy and it's a part I'm not very familiar with, but IIRC it's linked to the fact that under a tty Emacs treats SIGINT as an input key (corresponding to `C-g` maybe?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me using C-c C-c

```
Current directory is /src/build/emacs-24.5/src/
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.7.1-0ubuntu5~14.04.2) 7.7.1
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
...
(gdb) run 
Starting program: /src/build/emacs-24.5/src/emacs 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
...
[New Thread 0xb4bffb40 (LWP 735)]
 C-c C-c(gdb) 
C-c C-c(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x815d7b8: file emacs.c, line 707.
(gdb)
```

But here are two other things to try. First is without the `-i=mi` option. The second is to use [realgud](https://github.com/rocky/emacs-dbgr) (available from MELPA); and in realgud this can be done in one of two ways. After `M-x load-library realgud`, then `M-x realgud:gdb` or you can go into a "shell" (comint) or "term" shell and run plain *gdb*, "set annotate 1", and then run the program. Run  `M-x realgud-track-mode` and set the debugger to be *gdb*.

Answer (score 1):

A working solution for myself:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<f6>") (lambda ()
                               (interactive)
                               (gud-stop-subjob)
                               (comint-interrupt-subjob)))
```

`comint-interrupt-subjob` is the command bound to `C-c C-c`, it sends `SIGINT` to subprocess, `gud-stop-subjob` will send string `"-interrupt-exec --all"` to `gdb mi` interface. Neither of them works for me, but when I apply both, suprise, I don't know why, tell me if anybody knows the reason.

btw, sometimes I have to press `Enter` after `F6`, sometimes not.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the `stop` command or you can use `C-c C-z` which sends the stop signal. You could also just add the new breakpoints, if the new breakpoints are after your current position, when you do `continue` it will stop in the new breakpoint. If the breakpoint is before your current position, then you can restart the program by doing `run` this will restart the process. You can find more information here [GUD Commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Commands-of-GUD.html#Commands-of-GUD)

UPDATE:
In that case, you might want to read [etc/DEBUG](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/etc/DEBUG).

As for the gdb shell, you can start it by doing: `C-u M-x gdb` and then pass the `-i=mi -p PID` as well as any other flag you might need.

Comment: I don't have a `gdb` shell (my program is already running) so I can't issue `gdb`'s `stop` command (I assume that's what you meant?).  Also, `C-c C-z` doesn't seem to do anything (nor does the `Stop` button in the toolbar)...  I'll edit my post for full repro instructions (I'm trying to debug `emacs` within a separate `emacs+gud` instance.